# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

Tags: angular

`const rootElem = view.rootNodes[0]; if (rootElem) { this.renderer.removeClass(rootElem, 'disabled'); }`

Here am getting that Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove') in the promise,
what am i missing ?

Comment: Please try this once:- this.renderer?.removeClass(rootElem, 'disabled'); }

Comment: @Govardhan need more details, please provide a working stackblitz with the issue and expected result!

Comment: @Naren can find the similar example here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-class-renderer2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It would be great if you can add stackblitz link with reproducible problem

Comment: @pankaj you are right but am not getting that reproducible page in that,so i shared a link that which have my render 2 and more details about removeClass.

Comment: @Govardhan check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am calling that remove calss as `<ng-container *appPermissions="'SOME_KEY'; group: ''"></ng-container>` inside appPermissions directive i have removeClass, as `<ng-container>` doesn't have any class and we can't add or remove class on that tag so `<div *appPermissions="'SOME_KEY'; group: ''"></div>` calling my directive in a div resolves the issue.